# Totally Unimodular matrix edited from ordinary matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, matroid-theory, total-unimodularity

Given a matrix $M\in\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$ is there an algorithm to tell if we can convert some of $1$s to $-1$s and make $M$ Totally Unimodular and output such a Totally Unimodular in polynomial in $mn$ time?